# Many tests in github actions cause econnreset error

Tags: node.js, github-actions, chai, fastify

I have 230 tests and on my own machine its passed always, but on the github in github actions, tests is often falling with econnreset problem:

`[0]   1) App [0]        Get full search result [0]          "before all" hook for "should search full list of collabraotions and users": [0]      Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:36421 [0]       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)`

And I don't know how fix this, and I will be happy if someone tell me reason and how fix it.

My througts was, that it caused by wrong ports, but after change ports to hardcode 3000, problem not left

UPDATE: node version is 16.14 on my own computer and in workflow

Comment: In the error message, you can see that it is failing because it cannot connect to the service that should be running on port 36421. So if your tests depend on some db/service you need to run them in github actions.

Comment: Could you try to run a single file within a single test and share it?

Comment: @David i dont have any services running on 36421 port. And I forgot tell that tests falling in different places on each run

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon the same. Its main problem that i cannot debug this

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon i ran one unit test, its passing